# IdeaVimでのウインドウサイズの変更方法

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

**環境**
Windows 10
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4
IdeaVim 0.48

vimでは下記のようなキーマップを設定し、ウインドウサイズの調整を行っています。

```
nnoremap <S-j> <C-w>10-
nnoremap <S-k> <C-w>10+
nnoremap <S-l> <C-w>10>
nnoremap <S-h> <C-w>10<
```

しかしこの設定はIdeaVimでは動作しませんでした。設定方法はないでしょうか？
:actionでIDEの機能を呼び出せるようなので(:action GotoClass 等)、何らかのactionを使えば実現できそうなのですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どっちもできません。
IdeaVIMには<C-W +>や<C-W ->は未実装で，IntelliJはエディタのリサイズをコマンドでできません（アクティブなツールウィンドウをリサイズするStrech to Left/Right/Top/Bottomしかないです）。